# In modelica is the Heatport of the Electrical.Analog.Basic.Resistor defined as output only? If yes, how?

Tags: modelica

I am learning modelica, going fine. Until the point that I wanted to demonstrate the acausality with a resistor to my colleague. The question we asked ourselves: what is the voltage drop and curent for a 1 Ohm resistor when the thermal power from the resistor is 1W (obviously the answer should be 1V, 1A). I do not get any other result than 0 V, 0A. Physically I am happy with the result, since I do not expect a resistor to turn into a power source once I heat it up, but I do not understand where in the code this causality is built into the resistor model. 
I traced back the modelica library through Resistor - ConditionalHeatPort - HeatPort_a - HeatPort, but as far as I understand modelica there are only acausal equations. Can anyone shine light on this?

Thanks!

Edit: answer to Rene Just Nielsen:

I was using the code below. The idea is that this given the fact that the heat flow out of the resistor is fixed at 1W, a current and voltage need to be established over the resistor in order to solve all equations. If I simulate this, the heatflow at the component fixedHeatFlow1 = 0 W, the current and the voltage are also both 0 V and 0 A. Of course this is consistent with each other, but not consistent with the fixed boundary condition of -1 W at the fixedHeatFlow1.

```
model ElectricalPowerFromHeat
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Resistor resistor1(R = 1, alpha = 0, useHeatPort = true) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-28, -46}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Ground ground1 annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {12, -80}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sources.FixedHeatFlow fixedHeatFlow1(Q_flow = -1, alpha = 1)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-68, 14}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
  connect(resistor1.n, ground1.p) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-18, -46}, {12, -46}, {12, -70}, {12, -70}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  connect(fixedHeatFlow1.port, resistor1.heatPort) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-58, 14}, {-28, 14}, {-28, -56}, {-28, -56}}, color = {191, 0, 0}));
  connect(resistor1.p, ground1.p) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-38, -46}, {-38, -60}, {12, -60}, {12, -70}}, color = {0, 0, 255}));
  annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "3.2.2")),
    experiment(StartTime = 0, StopTime = 1, Tolerance = 1e-06, Interval = 0.002));
end ElectricalPowerFromHeat;
```

I would anticipate that the resistor could act as a power source based on the equations inside the resistor:

```
  R_actual = R*(1 + alpha*(T_heatPort - T_ref));
  v = R_actual*i;
  LossPower = v*i;
```

Comment: Please post your model or code. That will make it easier to understand your problem.

Comment: There really is no causality defined for the heat port, as Hans shows very nicely with the inverted model in his answer.
Regarding your solution: It seems like the
loss power of 1W does not arrive at the thermal port of the resistor, because  0V and 0A is obviously not a valid solution. So how did you set 1W?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to find the voltage drop for a 1 Ohm resistor given that the heat-flow is 1W that can be modelled as follows. First you take a model that generates the heat-flow for a simple circuit (in VoltageToHeatFlow) and then you invert the signal (in the Test-model):

```
package ShowInvertPower
  model VoltageToHeatFlow
    Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Ground ground
      annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-22,-16},{-2,4}})));
    Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.HeatingResistor resistor(R_ref=1)
      annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-8,48},{12,68}})));
    Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.SignalVoltage signalVoltage
      annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-58,52},{-38,72}})));
    Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sensors.HeatFlowSensor heatFlowSensor
      annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{52,22},{72,42}})));
    Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Components.HeatCapacitor heatCapacitor(C=1)
      annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{84,36},{104,56}})));
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput Q_flow1
      "Heat flow from port_a to port_b as output signal"
      annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{96,-18},{116,2}})));
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput v1
      "Voltage between pin p and n (= p.v - n.v) as input signal"
      annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-126,-32},{-86,8}})));
  equation 
    connect(signalVoltage.n, resistor.p) annotation (Line(points={{-38,62},{-26,
            62},{-26,58},{-8,58}}, color={0,0,255}));
    connect(resistor.n, ground.p) annotation (Line(points={{12,58},{30,58},{30,4},
            {-12,4}}, color={0,0,255}));
    connect(signalVoltage.p, ground.p) annotation (Line(points={{-58,62},{-68,62},
            {-68,4},{-12,4}}, color={0,0,255}));
    connect(resistor.heatPort, heatFlowSensor.port_a) annotation (Line(points={{
            2,48},{28,48},{28,32},{52,32}}, color={191,0,0}));
    connect(heatFlowSensor.port_b, heatCapacitor.port) annotation (Line(points={
            {72,32},{84,32},{84,36},{94,36}}, color={191,0,0}));
    connect(heatFlowSensor.Q_flow, Q_flow1) annotation (Line(points={{62,22},{66,
            22},{66,-8},{106,-8}}, color={0,0,127}));
    connect(signalVoltage.v, v1) annotation (Line(points={{-48,74},{-106,74},{-106,
            -12}}, color={0,0,127}));
  end VoltageToHeatFlow;

  model Test
    ShowInvertPower.VoltageToHeatFlow voltageToHeatFlow annotation (Placement(
          transformation(
          extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
          rotation=180,
          origin={-2,58})));
    Modelica.Blocks.Math.InverseBlockConstraints inverseBlockConstraints
      annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-24,46},{16,70}})));
    Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant const(k=2)
      annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-86,46},{-66,66}})));
  equation 
    connect(voltageToHeatFlow.v1, inverseBlockConstraints.y2) annotation (Line(
          points={{8.6,59.2},{13.1,59.2},{13.1,58},{13,58}}, color={0,0,127}));
    connect(inverseBlockConstraints.u2, voltageToHeatFlow.Q_flow1) annotation (
        Line(points={{-20,58},{-12,58},{-12,58.8},{-12.6,58.8}}, color={0,0,127}));
    connect(const.y, inverseBlockConstraints.u1) annotation (Line(points={{-65,56},
            {-46,56},{-46,58},{-26,58}}, color={0,0,127}));
    annotation (Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false)), Diagram(
          coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=false)));
  end Test;
  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="3.2.3")));
end ShowInvertPower;
```

The result is that 1 V (and 1 A) is required. Obviously it can be modelled in simpler ways, but using inverse models in this way is a standard way in Modelica.

Comment: Thank Hans, I was not (yet) aware of this possibility within Modelica to invert problems. In this way the type of analysis I had in mind can be performed.